can we override the standard role hierarchy in salesforce
I am using lead object for that i want to implement the logic if the user's manager change then we have to revoke the access for that manager so he cant see the records but because of standard hirechy they are able to see the record
I can uncheck the checkbox for Grant Access because its not editable for standard object

Unfortunately, you can't change the standard role hierarchy settings for objects like Leads directly. Even if you uncheck the Grant Access Using Hierarchies option, it won't apply to standard objects. To handle access when a manager changes, you'll need to use custom Apex sharing rules to manage who can see what records.

I added the custom sharing but still the hirechy wise manager can see the records even if i revoke them and  and also deleted lead share record
